# Better way, than this, to rename files using Python

Tags: python, file-io

I am python newbie and am still discovering its wonders.

I wrote a script which renames a number of files :
from **Edison_03-08-2010-05-02-00_PM.7z** to **Edison_08-03-2010-05-02-00_PM.7z**

"**03-08**-2010" is changed to "**08-03**-2010"

The script is:

```
import os, os.path
location = "D:/codebase/_Backups"
files = os.listdir(location)

for oldfilename in files:
    parts = oldfilename.split("_")    
    dateparts = parts[1].split("-")

    newfilename = parts[0] + "_" + dateparts[1] + "-" + dateparts[0] + "-" + dateparts[2] + "-" + parts[2] + "_" + parts[3]

    print oldfilename + " : " + newfilename
    os.rename(os.path.join(location, oldfilename), os.path.join(location, newfilename))
```

What would be a better/more elegant way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
name, timestamp = oldfilename.split('_', 1)
day, month, timestamp = timestamp.split('-', 2)

newfilename = '%s_%s-%s-%s' % (name, day, month, timestamp)
```

Comment: You are dropping the final part.

Comment: @Amoss: and the first part. Since those aren't changed they didn't seem important to me ;)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I wanted this done via some nifty string splitting which is what your code does. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

`datetime`'s [`strptime` (parse time string) and `strftime` (format time string)](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) will do most of the heavy lifting for you:

```
import datetime

_IN_FORMAT = 'Edison_%d-%m-%Y-%I-%M-%S_%p.7z'
_OUT_FORMAT = 'Edison_%m-%d-%Y-%I-%M-%S_%p.7z'

oldfilename = 'Edison_03-08-2010-05-02-00_PM.7z'

# Parse to datetime.
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(oldfilename, _IN_FORMAT)

# Format to new format.
newfilename = dt.strftime(_OUT_FORMAT)
```

---

```
>>> print newfilename
Edison_08-03-2010-05-02-00_PM.7z
```

---

Edit: Originally I was using `%H` (Hour, 24-hour clock) where I should have used `%I` (Hour, 12-hour clock) because the OP used AM/PM. This is why my example output incorrectly contained `AM` instead of `PM`. This is all corrected now.

Comment: Nice ! I am sure this is going to come in handy. Thanks Jon-Eric !